# In LSTM why h_t output twice?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, pytorch

According the LSTM design:

[image]

The hidden state (ht) is output twice (1 and 2 in the picture).

1. If they are the same, why we need them twice ?
2. Is there a different use for each one of them ?
3. According to

> nn.lstm

there are 3 outputs (output, h_n, c_n).
I didnt understand what is the different between output and h_n ? (Doesn't they need to be the same) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ht was initially defined as a differential function, which value is the same in output and in the next LSTM cell.

LSTM uses the previous steps in a sequential way and chooses whether to memorize or forget according to h(t-1) and C(t-1) and the inner weights, to set h(t) and C(t). h(t) is the cell's output, and it is sent to the next cell in order to keep a sequential logic.

It is quite complex to explain in a few words but let's say that the forget and memorize weights are set during the training process thanks to an auto-regulated system (named "the constant error carrousel") that takes into account several scenarios and at the same time avoids the neurons to diverge during training.

See main publication: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/13853244_Long_Short-term_Memory

Note: Google spent 10 years understanding LSTM's publication. It's very complex but very interesting.